# Return url while login is encoded

Tags: bug, status-completed

If I click "log in" while on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions (for example), I'm redirected to https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=%2fquestions

I have this issue on Firefox (5.0), Chromium (12.0.742.124) but not on Midori (0.3.6).

Comment: After completing the login (I use a google id) I'm redirected to http://unix.stackexchange.com%2fquestions  Url is not decoded.

Answer (score 3):

A fix for this has been committed and will be live with our next deploy.